# Xamarin Forms Transalted Button click

Tags: button, xamarin.forms, click

I am creating a rounded menu with Xamarin Forms as Below.

[image]

The accent color is my Grid. Then I translatex and trnaslatey the buttons.

My issue is that the click button is not raised. I have also tried on the gesture recognizer of my stack panel. Same result.

The part of the code is below:

```
  <Grid BackgroundColor="Accent" Margin="0,0,0,10" VerticalOptions="End" HorizontalOptions="Center">


        <StackLayout x:Name="cat" TranslationX="-109" TranslationY="-102"
                            >
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="catBtn_Clicked"/>
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <Button Clicked="catBtn_Clicked"          WidthRequest="60" 
                            HeightRequest="60" 
                            FontSize="35"
                            CornerRadius="30" HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource RedColor}"
                            TextColor="White"
                            Text="{ x:Static local:GrialIconsFont.Calendar }" 
                            FontFamily="{ StaticResource IconsFontFamily }">
        </Button>
            <Label Text="{extensions:Translate Hello}" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: That's a great looking menu, is it for your own app or are you making a component to be shared. I can imagine it being transparent as a pop-up too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Make sure that your button is placed inside superView's bounds,
If a button is placed outside superView's bounds, the button will not clickable**.

You use `TranslationX="-109"` and `TranslationY="-102"` will make the button out of the bounds of StackLayout, so it won't response to the click event. You can add backgroundColor to stacklayout to see its bounds.

I would suggest you to add those buttons or labels directly to Grid and use [absolute-layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout), [relative-layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout) or other layout to fix their positions.

There are also some examples in Github you can refer, such as `CircleButtonMenu`, `Xamarin.Forms-RadialMenu`

Comment: hanks. I changed the translatex and translatey in the stackpanel and it still not works.

Comment: Ok I changed my layout disposition and it worked thanks to your help.